# Looking for python packages that can calculate nodes/region/edges while respecting X,Y coordinates of nodes

Tags: python, graph-theory

I have a list of cities (nodes) plotted in a 2D plane each given by an X,Y coordinate.
I now want to add roads (edges) to it, but the roads cannot intersect.  I want to create the most number of roads possible.  By count, not by total length.

In more general graph theory parlance, I think I want the maximum number of edges (or regions?? maybe it's the same thing), where edges do not intersect in 2-dimensions, for a given set of Nodes at X,Y points.

In a brief view of NetworkX, it seems that they generate Graphs by  making "nodes" but nodes can be "anywhere" and cannot force nodes to be at a certain location with respect to each other (they have abstracted too far!).

Edit:  [networkx add_node with specific position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804730/networkx-add-node-with-specific-position)
suggests that you can plot them in a given location. @Stef thanks!!

1. Am i thinking about the problem correctly?
2. Can I visualize using some python package my Nodes/edges, where this package can automatically calculate the proper edges given a set of nodes?
3. Is automatically finding the maximum number of non-intersecting edges a thing (and what is this called so I can find out  more about it?)

Very possibly similar to this question, but this question wasn't really answered and from 8 years ago ([Algorithm for finding minimal cycle basis of planar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892692/algorithm-for-finding-minimal-cycle-basis-of-planar-graph))

Comment: *"In a brief view of NetworkX, it seems that they generate Graphs by making "nodes" but nodes can be "anywhere" and cannot force nodes to be at a certain location with respect to each other (they have abstracted too far!)."* Not true. You can add coordinates to nodes.

Comment: I would go about it like this: (1) Find a simple formula to tell whether two edges in this graph G would intersect or not, given the coordinates of their nodes. (2) Build a new graph L where there is one node in L representing each edge from G, and an edge between two nodes in L iff the two corresponding edges in G would intersect. (3) Your problem is now the [maximum independent set problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) in L.

Comment: Cities exist on a sphere, approximately, not a 2D plane.  Perhaps you should be thinking about great circles connecting cities?  This problem, on a 2D plane, is very important in circuit board layout - a great deal of work is available both practical and theoretical.  If you want a specific answer to a specific problem, you need to detail what the real problem is that you are trying to solve.  It also helps if you post the code you have used to attempt a solution.

Comment: @Stef  will check out the independent set problem!  looks promising.  Are there any packages that have some of these common type of algorithms for graphs already created that you recommend?

Comment: @ravenspoint, i see your point, perhaps i can describe it as a circuit board layout to better capture what im looking for.  Still looking at the proper way of thinking about solution to see if I am on the right track.

Comment: Please describe your actual problem!  If it is not really cities and not a circuit board, what is it?

Comment: @user1639926 networkx has [maximal_independent_set](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.mis.maximal_independent_set.html), an exact algorithm that returns an independent set such that you can't add extra nodes to it, and [maximum_independent_set](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.clique.maximum_independent_set.html), an approximate algorithm that returns an approximate maximum independent set.

Comment: @user1639926 The maximum independent set problem is NP-hard, which means there is no algorithm which is both fast and returns the optimal solution, in the general case. Of course, real-life is full of cases which are not the general case, and this problem has been studied a lot, which is why ravenspoint is telling you to add more details about your precise problem.